# WooCommerce how to get a clean label of a product attributes on front end

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, product-variations

So, I'm successfully adding products, variations with attributes, etc in a plugin I'm writing. The problem I'm having is that on the frontend the attributes appear as the raw name (e.g. pa_variation_name) rather than a clean looking title (e.g. Variation Name).

I am adding the attribute to the parent product as follows...

```php
$product = wc_get_product($post_id);
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_name('pa_variation_name');
$attribute->set_options($attributes_array);
$attribute->set_visible(true);
$attribute->set_variation(true);
$attributes[] = $attribute;

$product->set_attributes($attributes);

$product->save();
```

And adding the data to the individual variations like this:

```php
update_post_meta($variation_id, 'attribute_pa_variation_name', $args['Description']);
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but **how can I set a clean title so I don't have 'pa_whatever' appearing on the frontend?**

Answer (score 2):

> *"on the frontend the attributes appear as the raw name (e.g. pa_variation_name) rather than a clean looking title (e.g. Variation Name)."*

I would use woocommerce `wc_attribute_label` function. Like this:

```php
wc_attribute_label( $attribute->->get_name() );
```

For example if I run it on one of my products:

```php
$attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute_options) 
{
  echo wc_attribute_label($attribute_name);
}
```

It'll output this:

[image]

**Note:**

- It's been capitalized.
- `pa_` has been removed.

But if I run my code without `wc_attribute_label`:

```php
$attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute_options) 
{
  echo $attribute_name;
}
```

It'll output this:

[image]

---

For more details you could checkout [wc_attribute_label](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/7891d382c4cbe48d34d93dd85a294467f16fd33e/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-attribute-functions.php#L180) function.